# Need help populating a listbox

Tags: c#

So far i have this code in a search button:

```
string path = "C:\\Work\\TestDirectory";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach (var f in files)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
```

This code should bring back a list so how would i get the list to show in a textbox?

I am a beginner so links would also help.

Comment: This is not a vba question so I have removed the tag

Comment: No, I did... @99moorem

Comment: the visual studio tag has also been removed... why?

Comment: This follows on from your previous question...did you even try the code above?  It won't currently filter the files.

Comment: The [tag:visual-studio] tag? Because this is a C# question, and the question doesn't have anything to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: i dont know what i am doing

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I think the OP meant ListBox

Comment: @PatrickHofman i am making this in visual studio! it has everything to do with it

Comment: No, it does not. Would you tag it chair because you sit on one?

Comment: Dear everyone else: here is the original question if you need some context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010308/i-want-to-search-for-files-based-on-certain-file-attributes/36010649#36010649.  he now wants to put a list of strings in a list box

Comment: @PatrickHofman okay "buddy"

Comment: I get the impression you don't like to search for things. Have you tried something called 'Google'? Perhaps typing 'c# adding items to listbox'?

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite *vague*. So the answer depends on what you *actually want*:

```
  string path = "C:\\Work\\TestDirectory";
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

If you want to have a `List<String>`:

```
  List<String> list = files.ToList();
```

In case you want to represent files in a `TextBox`:

```
  MyTextBox.Text = String.Join(", ", files);
```

Or (just files without directories)

```
  MyTextBox.Text = String.Join(", ", files.Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file)));
```

If you want to put files into `ListBox`:

```
  MyListBox.Items.AddRange(files);
```